# Flutter App not installing on Android Real device

Tags: macos, flutter

i am running my app on Macbook pro ! Every thing is perfect but my app is not running on android this error comes always please can you look into ! i follow the all the steps to Setup Flutter on MacOs..! App is running on iOS simulator...but not running on Android Device

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Nokia 5 1 Plus in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 
'/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by 
Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update or install the Java JDK: [oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html](https://oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html), and make sure it's in the correct location.

> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation
> '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by
> Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

This line makes this clear.

Comment: can you please tell me where is the exact location ! so i can put this jdk

Comment: It literally says in the message. I can't help more than that because I have no idea what format that path is (its not a Windows path, so I can't help). Try installing to the default location? You need to learn to actually read the error messages and do some research before posting questions like this.